# About Parity squared

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Feynman's old book, "Theory of fundamental processes",page 33, when he talk about the mirror-reflection operation on a quantum state $\phi$, where the mirror-image state is $\phi'$,
he wrote

"The principle of superposition requires that $\phi'=P\phi$ where $P$ is a linear operator. But $P\phi'=\phi$ with in the phase factor. Therefore $P^2=1$. "

What is the meaning of "within the phase factor"? Does this mean $P\phi'=e^{i\alpha}\phi$, where $\alpha$ is a constant? If this is the case, $P^2$ should be $e^{i\alpha}$, but not $1$. Is this correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : An overall phase factor is unobservable, and thus is an internal symmetry of the system, which can be pasted on the old parity operator to define a new parity operator which satisfies the same relations.

Long answer : Define a parity transform $\mathcal{P}$ as an unitary operator which acts as $\mathcal{P}\psi_{r}=e^{i\phi/2}\psi_{-r}$. Then, $\mathcal{P}^2\psi_{r}=e^{i\phi}\psi_{r}$, since an overall phase factor is unobservable. Thus, the operator $\mathcal{P}^2$ leaves the spacetime invariant, and so is an internal symmetry of the system that rotates the eigenstates by a phase of $e^{i\phi}$.
Now, if $\mathcal{P}^2$ is an elelment $e^{iQ}\in\mathrm{U(1)}$, then so is $e^{-iQ}$ and hence is also a symmetry. So, we can define $\mathcal{P}':=\mathcal{P}e^{-iQ/2}$ as our new parity operator, which acts in the same way as our old definition did, and this gives us that $\mathcal{P}^2=1$, as Feynman claimed. Thus upto a phase factor means that these 2 definitions are equivalent modulo a phase factor, which is itself unobservable.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker and want to confirm one thing: Is  "within the phase factor" really the same as "up to a phase factor"?

Comment: Yes, it is as you say it. You can also rephrase it as "modulo a phase factor".

Comment: For one particle we can always absorb the phase into the redefinition of parity operator to have $P^2=1$. But if there are several species of particles, each gains a phase by the action of $P^2$, I doubt we can make $P^2=1$ for all of them. And relative phases of different particles under the transformation are physically significant.